# Passing a variable from jsp page to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, html

If a user clicks on the following, he will be send to another page via the servlet.

```
<li><a method="POST" href="ToolServlet?action=goToUserRolesOverview">SOME TEXT</a></li>
```

I want to send a variable with the submit to the servlet, I came up with this:

```
<li><a method="POST" href="ToolServlet?action=goToUserRolesOverview">SOME TEXT<input type="hidden" name="user_emailHidden" id="user_emailHidden" /></a></li>
```

To fill in the hidden 'user_emailHidden', I do the following JavaScript:

```
console.log("user_email: " + params.user_email); /*Testing only: it works */
document.getElementById("user_emailHidden").value = params.user_email;
```

The value is set to the hidden variable, I tested this with:

```
console.log("user_email test: " + document.getElementById("user_emailHidden").value);
```

This is not working. Any help on how to include the variable with the submit when the user clicks on this item?

Thanks

Comment: remove method="POST"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still get a `null` on the servlet side.

Comment: Can you please post Servlet code?

Comment: I sure can, this code is located in a method that is called when the user clicks on the button in the UI: `System.out.println(request.getParameter("user_emailHidden"));` This will print out `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solutions.

For the link, I send the variable with the url to the servlet as so:

```
<li id="insertUserEmail"><a href="ToolServlet?action=goToUserRolesOverview&user_emailHidden=">SOME TEXT</a></li>
```

To add the *user-email* to the end of the **href**:

```
$('#insertUserEmail a').attr('href',function(i,str) {
    return str + params.user_email;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> this way to send variable with the url to the servlet .

**javaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function navigate() {
    var userEmail = document.getElementById('user_emailHidden').value;
    window.location = '${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/ToolServlet?id='
            + userEmail;
}</script>
```

**href**

```
<a href="" onclick="return navigate();">SOME TEXT</a> <input
        type="hidden" name="user_emailHidden" id="user_emailHidden"
        value="123546" /></a>
```

**Servlet**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ToolServlet")
public void getEmailId(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("id"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this is different from what I want to achieve. I do not want to get the action value, I want to get the _user_emailHidden_ value that has been set by the JavaScript code.

Comment: Your given solution got me thinking. I am doing this now `<li><a href="ToolServlet?action=goToUserRolesOverview&user_emailHidden=test">SOME TEXT</a></li>`. How can I insert the _user_emailHidden_ via javascript, where _test_ is?